# Why is it a bad idea to override Plone's main_template.pt?

Tags: plone

I've heard it's a bad idea to override Plone's `main_template.pt`. Why is that a bad idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not considered a bad idea, as long as you are a bit careful about it, and know the implications.

You just have to make sure to do a comparison from the old to the new version of the standard template (ie. when upgrading from Plone 3.3 to 4.0) and update your custom main_template accordingly.

Between major versions, the main_template can change, and you want your custom version to have the same capabilities.

Comment: Thanks. My new Plone theme is coming along nicely with this technique.

Answer (score 1):

As of plone 4.2, plone.app.theming and diazo give you the level of control you need over the whole page with less upgrade issues of overriding main_template.

Comment: However this kind of theme has a different and unfamiliar-to-me development process.

Comment: yes it is completely new, however it's easy to learn and worth the effort. It allows a cleaner way all sorts of aspects of your site all in one place. With plone5 you will unlikely be able to override main_template so this could be your only option.